# SQL to extract distinct values from an UNION query ordered by values that are not required

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the TOP 20 DISTINCT address records from a query with a UNION...

The issue is that I want to order by date first - so the customer sees the most recent - but each date makes the row unique and leaves me with a ton of replica addresses (please see below).

```
SELECT 
    CB.CustomerGuid, CB.DisplayAddress, CB.LocatorId 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         B.CustomerGuid, CAST(B.PickupDateTime AS DATE) AS TravelDate, 
         B.PickupDisplayAddress AS DisplayAddress, B.PickupAddressId AS LocatorId
     FROM 
         Bookings B
     WHERE 
         CustomerGuid = '463a20f2-a874-4964-865d-70d71065a69b'

     UNION 

     SELECT 
         B2.CustomerGuid, CAST(B2.PickupDateTime AS DATE) AS TravelDate, 
         B2.DestinationDisplayAddress AS DisplayAddress, B2.PickupAddressId AS LocatorId
     FROM 
         Bookings B2
     WHERE 
         CustomerGuid = '463a20f2-a874-4964-865d-70d71065a69b'
     ORDER BY 
         TravelDate DESC) AS CB
```

I felt the approach would be make the union query a subquery and query that (without the date) as DISTINCT but I have since learned that the order of rows in the result set is ultimately controlled by the ORDER BY clause in the outer SELECT. This therefore gives me the error:

*The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.*

How do I get around this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this I think would work, assuming it doesn't matter which traveldate you sort by:

```
SELECT TOP 20 CB.CustomerGuid, CB.DisplayAddress, CB.LocatorId FROM 
(SELECT B.CustomerGuid, CAST(B.PickupDateTime AS DATE) AS TravelDate, 
B.PickupDisplayAddress AS DisplayAddress, B.PickupAddressId AS LocatorId
FROM Bookings B
WHERE CustomerGuid = '463a20f2-a874-4964-865d-70d71065a69b'
UNION 
SELECT B2.CustomerGuid, CAST(B2.PickupDateTime AS DATE) AS TravelDate, 
B2.DestinationDisplayAddress AS DisplayAddress, B2.PickupAddressId AS LocatorId
FROM Bookings B2
WHERE CustomerGuid = '463a20f2-a874-4964-865d-70d71065a69b'
) AS CB
GROUP BY CB.CustomerGuid, CB.DisplayAddress, CB.LocatorId
ORDER BY MAX(TravelDate) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks @JJ32. That definitely works by using the 'MAX' function. Remove it and the same error applies... Love to understand why adding MAX gets around the issue. Big thanks to you.